# Apparent circular import without known cause

Tags: python, flask

I have an import error that I've been trying to solve for the past two days and still haven't been able to figure out.

I'm building a REST API and I've put my source into its own module titled `cruiser`. I'm implementing an app factory pattern. In `__main__.py` I have `from cruiser import create_app, models, util`. `create_app` is defined in `__init__.py`.

Here are the entire contents of `__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from . import config
from .external import init_app

# App factory function
def create_app(config_data):
    app = Flask('cruiser')
    app.config.from_object(config.DevelopmentConfig)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
    external.init_app(app)
    return app
```

When running my application locally with `python -m cruiser` the application returns the following error: `from cruiser import create_app, models, util - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cruiser'` (edited)

Strangely, commenting out `app.config.from_object(config.DevelopmentConfig)` in `__init__.py` fixes the error. This is not a real solution of course since then my app is missing vital configuration info. Also, in this example the parameter (`config.DevelopmentConfig`) is hard-coded, as originally `config_data` was passed to it but I changed it to make sure the data being passed wasn't the actual issue.

I just don't get how the line in `__init__.py` relates to the import error at all.

Later on I put a bunch of `print()`s throughout my code to see what was going on. They *all* printed, even the ones after the actual `create_app` function runs in `__main__.py`. After these all printed into the console Flask restarted its server (not sure if this is supposed to happen), as I some along the lines of `restarting server...` *after* which the import error was reported.

It was suggested that this was a problem with the Flask development server. After running my app with the Flask CLI it launched without errors. However I had a new problem: all the endpoints of my API returned 404s, even though there were no errors reported in the console (Flask's debug mode was on).

Is this a problem with my code or the server? If the problem is with my code how might I go about finding the solution? If this is a server problem, how can I get the code running locally? Having to upload to the actual server to test would be less than desirable to say the least.